# Docker maven image is creating target folder owned by root and Jenkins cannot remove it from its workspace

Tags: java, maven, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using edited [docker-maven](https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/tree/master/) image to compile java maven projects using Jenkins pipeline script. I mount jenkins workspace as volume for the docker. One of the first groovy scripts that run inside the pipeline cleans up the whole workspace.

However the target folder with all containings (.war file, surefire reports etc.) is created as root:root permissions. All the files are also owned by root and therefore the pipeline is failing within next run because it can not clean up workspace (Permission denied).

I investigated this issue a lot and I found two workarounds:

- From [official maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers)  - Use settings.xml and specify: *filePermissions* to 777 and *directoryPermissions* to 777. I think it is dirty fix and should not be applied...
- Add Jenkins to sudoers and invoke a script with sudo rm -rf + on the workspace - but since we use many slave machines I would have to do this on many machines and I belive that there is a better way.

This is how my Dockerfile for maven image looks like:

```
FROM <our-internal-image>

RUN export http_proxy=$HTTP_PROXY && \
    export https_proxy=$HTTPS_PROXY && \
    zypper -n in tar which java-1_8_0-openjdk java-1_8_0-openjdk-devel && \
    zypper clean && \
    SUSEConnect --cleanup

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref && \
    curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/3.6.0/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.0-bin.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 && \
    rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz && \
    ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk
ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "/root/.m2"

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mvn"]
```

And this is how I invoke the compilation of our maven based module (docker-maven is name for the image created based on the Dockerfile):

```
def _compileMavenModule = {
    stage('Build - compile maven module') {
        sh "docker run " +
                "--name maven-module-${BUILD_ID} " +
                "--rm " +
                "-v ${WORKSPACE}:/build " +
                "-e http_proxy=\"${http_proxy}\" " +
                "-e https_proxy=\"${https_proxy}\" " +
                "-e HTTP_PROXY=\"${http_proxy}\" " +
                "-e HTTPS_PROXY=\"${https_proxy}\" " +
                "-e MAVEN_OPTS=\"-Dhttp.proxyHost=<HTTP_PROXY> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<HTTP_PROXY_PORT>-Dhttps.proxyHost=HTTP_PROXY> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<HTTP_PROXY_PORT>\" " +
                "docker-maven clean package -f /build/path-to-maven-repository/pom.xml"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to run maven inside the docker image as jenkins? Or to make the files created by this docker image be jenkins:jenkins? All the other images that run ANT targets create output with jenkins:jenkins privileges. Only the maven does not... Maybe I am not aware of some setting or something. Help me please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass [`--user`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user) option in [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run):

```
sh "docker run " +
            "--name maven-module-${BUILD_ID} " +
            "--user ${env.BUILD_USER_ID}:${env.BUILD_USER_ID}" +
            "--rm " +
            "-v ${WORKSPACE}:/build " +
            "-e http_proxy=\"${http_proxy}\" " +
            "-e https_proxy=\"${https_proxy}\" " +
            "-e HTTP_PROXY=\"${http_proxy}\" " +
            "-e HTTPS_PROXY=\"${https_proxy}\" " +
            "-e MAVEN_OPTS=\"-Dhttp.proxyHost=<HTTP_PROXY> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<HTTP_PROXY_PORT>-Dhttps.proxyHost=HTTP_PROXY> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<HTTP_PROXY_PORT>\" " +
            "docker-maven clean package -f /build/path-to-maven-repository/pom.xml"
}
```

This will pass your current user as user and group inside Docker container.

**EDIT**: If those variables are empty, you can try to get the values using bash:

```
user = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'id -u').trim()
group = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'id -g').trim()
sh "docker run " +
            "--name maven-module-${BUILD_ID} " +
            "--user $user:$group" +
            …
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me an error because the values are null:null.
`docker: Error response from daemon: linux spec user: unable to find user null: no matching entries in passwd file.`

Comment: Nevermind. This gave me a hint. I specified the `--user` flag with `jenkins:jenkins` values and I have added `RUN groupadd jenkins && \
useradd -ms /bin/bash jenkins -g jenkins` to the Dockerfile and It works fine. The target is now generated as jenkins:jenkins and Jenkins can remove it from its ownspace on re-run. Thank You for the hint anyway! :)

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Comment: Weird. It works only if jenkins is first system user on linux (UID and GID 1000:1000). On other system when I checked it - the job failed becasue of `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project shell-controller: Cannot create resource output directory:`. I noticed that on this system jenkins is 1001:1001. Is there some kind of correlation?

In this case I think i must figure out a different, more error-proof solution. Do You have any idea?

Comment: Ok now I verified this on two different environments and it works correctly! Thanks again!